# Tcl binary scan is not setting bytes

Tags: tcl

I am new to tcl and I need to read a binary file and compare first and last byte of data but I discovered that binary scan is not working for me (even the [examples](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/binary+scan))

Here is the snippet

```
set fp [open $temp_file_name]
defer { close $fp }
fconfigure $fp -translation binary

# ...

seek $fp 0
set m [binary scan [read $fp 1] h* v]

puts $v

# can't read "v": no such variable 
# m is 0
```

With the example

```sh
> puts [binary scan abcdefg s3s first second]
> puts $first
## can't read "first": no such variable
> puts $second
## can't read "second": no such variable
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What Tcl extension are you using?  There is no defer command in Tcl.  I just tried a binary scan on /usr/bin/ls, and it works.

Comment: http://jim.tcl.tk/fossil/doc/trunk/Tcl_shipped.html#_defer I am using Jimtcl

Comment: From the documentation, it appears 'binary' is based on the 'pack/unpack' commands.   You may be better off trying to getting `unpack` to work on your data.

Comment: Yes, trying with `unpack` only.

The problem is with MacOSX because the same works perfectly in my Linux computer

Answer (score 1):

The result of `binary scan` is the number of format groups that have been satisfied. If we consider the case:

```
binary scan abcdefg s3s first second
```

The result of this is `1`, because there are enough bytes to only satisfy the first format group, `s3`. That consumes six bytes (three little-endian 16-bit quantities, using up `abcdef`). There's insufficient data to satisfy the following `s`; there'd need to be another byte for that.

```
% info patchlevel
8.6.10
% puts [binary scan abcdefg s3s first second]
1
% puts $first
25185 25699 26213
% puts $second
can't read "second": no such variable
```

With the other code:

```
set m [binary scan [read $fp 1] h* v]
```

This will read a byte from the stream, convert into little-endian hex digits (I don't like the `h` conversion very much; `H` seems more sensible to me, especially for single bytes) and stores all those hex characters in the variable `v`. It *should* return 1 if anything is read from the stream at all.

---

I've no idea at all why `binary scan` is not working for you. It does not appear to be functioning in accordance with documented behaviour at all. To double-check, you haven't accidentally replaced the `::binary` or `::tcl::binary::scan` (which is the default implementation of `binary scan`) commands, have you?

Since things are behaving massively out of spec, it's hard to suggest how to fix that.

Comment: It's a bit like taking a car into a mechanic complaining that the ride is a bit bumpy and they discover that one of the wheels is square. Something is terribly wrong!

Comment: I think the problem is with MacOSX because my branch works well in Linux, although not sure if its my mac's specific problem or just MacOSX in general

Comment: It works just like @Donal says it does on macos 10.12.6 running the standard tclsh that comes with the OS, patchlevel 8.5.9. If the tclsh on Linux can get 4 two-byte values when given only 7 bytes... well, ...  :-)  I use binary scan quite a lot on macos, and it does work. When I add one more character to the 'abc..' string, then `binary scan` says it correctly converted two values (not 1) and both `first` and `second` have values.  Yes, it's very unfortunate that the manual page for `binary` has this (broken) example.